# A question about longitudinal data analysis and generalized linear mixed models

Tags: r, glmm, longitudinal-data-analysis

I have 1 time-varying predictor (the main predictor) and many other time-invariant predictors, and the outcome variable is also time-varying. Because the unit for the outcome and the time-varying predictor is different, I want to standardize the two variables to facilitate comparison, while keeping all other time-invariant predictors unstandardized.

Conceptually, I think this is OK but I am not sure if this (standardize the two variables) will cause some mathematical problems. Does anyone know what I plan to is appropriate or not? What is the best way to treat my variables (such as standardize or mean-center) in order for easy comparison the change between the time-varying predictor and the outcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Leaving regression outcomes and inputs in their original units is *desirable* because the association measure can be interpreted geometrically as a slope relating them. For instance, if you related miles driven by a car to the gas fueled between stops, the slope describes fuel efficiency as *miles per gallon*. It's intuitive.
2. The most popular approach to making a unitless quantity involves dividing the outcome by a *measure of spread*. The most popular measure of spread is the standard deviation. The issue with this is you need a sophisticated approach to measuring an individual-level SD.. that involves fitting a mixed model with untransformed units! The question remains: why make so much work for yourself?
3. When necessary, it's good practice to scale exposures/outcomes by reasonable (unitless) constants to avoid reporting outcomes of unfathomable magnitude. For instance, relating cancer incidence to a one *day* difference in age is too small to make sense. Scale age by a 5 or 10 year difference, and the effects are far more meaningful.

Comment: These are great answers! super helpful!
I have a follow-up question. My outcome variable is ranged from 0-100 and the time-varying predictor variable is ranged from 0-20, and they are both simultaneously measured at 3 different times. 
The predictor variable is calculated as the sum of 5 variables with each scored as (0, 1, 2, 3, 4). The outcome variable is the mean of 2 variables, with each ranged as (0, 25, 50, 75, 100). 
My understanding is I should time the predictor by 5 and not changing any other variables. Do you think my understanding is correct?
Thank you so much!

Comment: @YanSu impossible to say anything in abstract. Just think on how you will describe the result to a colleague.

Comment: Yes. It makes sense. Thank you so much for your comments!